# How do I convert this function into ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can you help me convert this function into ActionScript 3.0?

```
for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
    _root["pemain"+i].onEnterFrame = function() {
        ulartangga();
        if (this.temp_nomor<this.nomor) {
            this.temp_nomor++;
        }
        this._x = _root["kotak"+this.temp_nomor]._x;
        this._y = _root["kotak"+this.temp_nomor]._y;
    };
}
```

I followed a tutorial from http://warungflash.com/2009/05/ular-tangga-player-vs-player/

and i have tried to convert into this :

```
function onEnterFrame() {
//ulartangga();
if (this.temp_nomor<this.nomor) {
    this.temp_nomor++;
}
this.x = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].x;
this.y = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].y;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which error are you getting? http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: I am a beginner, and I do not understand how to convert '_root["pemain"+i].onEnterFrame = function()' into as3.. thx

Comment: So what have you tried? It's important to understand, otherwise any answer will be worthless.

Comment: i have tried to convert into this :
       function onEnterFrame() {
  //ulartangga();
  if (this.temp_nomor<this.nomor) {
   this.temp_nomor++;
  }
  this.x = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].x;
  this.y = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].y;
        }

Comment: Good! :) Then you should use the "edit" link of your post, add a line EDIT : and then paste your code there! That`s the way things are done here ;) If people see what you have tried, they will be more incline to help you, even faster! You should always do that, it makes your question way more valuable and easy to answer. If you do so, I will upvote your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enter-frame should be an EventListener. Assuming your other code is correct, this should work.

```
import flash.events.Event;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void{
    if (this.temp_nomor<this.nomor) {
        this.temp_nomor++;
    }
    this.x = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].x;
    this.y = stage["kotak"+this.temp_nomor].y;
}
```

Comment: thx for your help, but i still have problem
'Property kotak3 not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.'..